# Find index of a list of floats in a list of floats

Tags: python, list

I have a function that returns all local maximum using the index of these local maxes. After I get each local max that is above the average I would then like to return the index of those local maxes from the game_log list. Essentially, I want to return  the index of `[38.2,34.5,34.5]` from the game_log list. Is there a way to search a list of floats with a list of floats and get the corresponding indexes in a list?

```
import numpy as np
local_max = [ 3,  6,  8, 10]
game_log = [22.7, 16.7, 18.5, 38.2, 1.5, 8.6,
            12.6, 7.4, 34.5, 23.2, 34.5, 20.5, 24.0, 35.1]

average_points = sum(game_log) / len(game_log)

def filter_local_max_under_avg(game_log, local_max_list, avg):
  res_list = [game_log[i] for i in local_max_list]
  filtered_list = [i for i in res_list if i >= avg]
  return filtered_list

vals = filter_local_max_under_avg(game_log, local_max, average_points)
print(vals)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are okay with continuing to use the function which returns the indexes of the local maxes, it sounds like you just need a second function which checks if they are above the average. Something like:

```
def filter_local_max_under_avg(game_log, local_max, average_points):
    res = list()
    for idx in local_max:
        if game_log[idx] > average_points:
            res.append(idx)
    return res
```

or as a generator...

```
def filter_local_max_under_avg(game_log, local_max, average_points):
    for idx in local_max:
        if game_log[idx] > average_points:
            yield idx
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general function for searching one list against another and returning a list of the matching indexes

```
def get_matches(target: list, query: list) -> list:
    result = []
        for x in query:
        try:
            temp = target.index(x) 
            result.append(temp)
        except ValueError: #thrown if no match found
            pass
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will give you the index of the float, you can then create a list from it in a loop. You'll have to use try/except if you have floats that aren't in the index.

```
game_log.index(18.5)
# 2
```